# How to Push only one object and update it into Array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating simple App using Vanilla JavaScript, I have some issue, Let's explain my problem,In the beginning i have empty array, I want to push some values from Input field, and it's works fine, but i want to push only one object into `arrOfObj:[]`, that means i want replace old value by new value, without changing the length.

```js
var arrOfObj = [];
function pushObject() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('mainInput').value;
  arrOfObj.push({ id: 1, value: inputVal });
  console.log(arrOfObj);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pushObject()">click</button>
<input type="text" id="mainInput">
```

Comment: If I am getting this right you need `arrObj` to contain the most recent value of `text input` before click is pressed?

Comment: why not `arrOfObj[0] = {'id':1, 'value':inputVal}`?

Comment: @stark Exactly i want to update always firs value

Comment: Then why have a list `arrObj` why not update single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using `push`, you can directly replace the first index with your new object

```
    var arrOfObj = [];
    function pushObject(){
     var inputVal = document.getElementById('mainInput').value
     //replace the first value of array
     arrOfObj[0] = {'id':1, 'value':inputVal};
      console.log(arrOfObj)
    }

    
    <button onclick="pushObject()">click</button>
    <input type="text" id="mainInput">
```

Comment: You got to update the function name to something like "updateObject" too then

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply updating the 0th element of your array if there is one.

```js
var arrOfObj = [];
function pushObject(){
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('mainInput').value
  if (arrOfObj[0]) {
    arrOfObj[0].value = inputVal
  } else {
    arrOfObj.push({'id':1, 'value':inputVal})
  }
  console.log(arrOfObj)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pushObject()">click</button>
<input type="text" id="mainInput">
```